# Nesting ng-repeat at single level of DOM

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

I have nested collections, as follows:

```
[
  {
    name:    "foo",
    members: ["foo1","foo2"]
  }, {
    name:    "bar",
    members: ["bar1","bar2","bar3"]
  }, {
    name:    "qux",
    members: []
  }
]
```

From this, I would like to generate the following markup:

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row" rowspan="2">foo</th>
    <td>foo1</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>foo2</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <th scope="row" rowspan="3">bar</th>
    <td>bar1</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>bar2</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td>bar3</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

It would also be acceptable to repeat the `<th>` cells in each row, if `rowspan` proves too awkward to work with:

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">foo</th>
    <td>foo1</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <th scope="row">foo</th>
    <td>foo2</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <th scope="row">bar</th>
    <td>bar1</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <th scope="row">bar</th>
    <td>bar2</td>
  </tr><tr>
    <th scope="row">bar</th>
    <td>bar3</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

What is the idiomatic way to accomplish a task like this using AngularJS?  In particular, I'm struggling to see how one can perform a *nested* `ng-repeat` at a single level of the DOM (i.e. on the `<tr>` element).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add several repeats on one tag. But you can add ng-repeat to `tbody` into your table

```
<table>
  <tbody ng-repeat="row in data">
     <tr ng-repeat="member in row.members">
       <th scope="row" rowspan="{{row.members.length}}" ng-if="$first">{{row.name}}</th>
       <td>{{member}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Then you can hide extra `th`'s using `ng-if` and `$first` – this is local property in `ng-repeat` which becomes true on first element in repeat.

Look at [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/lucihimara/1/edit?html,js,output) with result